# What's the difference between Map and Mapping in Isabelle?

Tags: functional-programming, theory, isabelle

So I went to the internet, and I found these:

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/Map.html (Map)

https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Library/Mapping.html (Mapping)

Two theories beginning with the word "Map". I read through them for a good while and I couldn't really discern any notable differences between them. Is there a time when I should use the former rather than the latter and vice versa?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Map.thy` gives you some vocabulary to talk about partial functions, written as `'a ⇀ 'b`, which is an abbreviation for `'a ⇒ 'b option`.

The `Mapping` theory, on the other hand, wraps that into a new type of partial functions, which is useful for code generation. If you tried to export code for things involving partial functions of type `'a ⇀ 'b`, you would get literally `'a ⇒ 'b option` in the exported code, which means that e.g. things like asking for the domain of such a function will simply not be executable.

With `Mapping`, on the other hand, you can export to a more sensible implementation of (finite) maps, such as association lists or red-black trees.

So, short answer: Don't worry about `Mapping` except if (and when) you want to export executable code.